# Java hidden methods

Tags: java, game-engine

I'm creating a new game engine in Java and I want to provide GameWindow class with some public static methods like setTitle(), resize() but I want to create one more method that will be able to create a whole window. This method should be accessible only by Engine's class to don't allow create window by developers (so this method will be called ONLY by Engine as I said in correct moment of initialization).

And now how to hide this method from world? I'm looking for something like "friend" way in c++.

Those classes (Engine and GameWindow class) are in separate packages.

P.s. I found a way with abstract classes in some other engines but if it is possible, could somebody explain me how to do that?

Comment: no friend class in java, but with interface, subclasses, you can do a lot ...

Comment: Why not use the protected modifier and just package the needed classes in one package. It makes sense to have things related to window creation in one package. Rethinking the structure of the engine may not be a bad idea. (Just a suggestion)

Comment: @Ashwin Gupta I prefer to keep classes like Engine, GameWindow, MouseInput in different packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use following trick:

```
class GameWindow {
  GameWindow() {...}
  protected void methodOnlyforEngine() {...}
  ...
}
class Engine {
  private class GameWindowProxy extends GameWindow {
     GameWindowProxy(GameWindow ex) { super();...}
  }

  private final GameWindowProxy proxy;
  Engine(GameWindow window) {
     proxy = new GameWindowProxy(window);
  }
  ...
  proxy.methodOnlyforEngine(); 
}
```